# How do I enter "yui" with wordflow?

Tags: 8.1, wordflow

How do I enter "yui" by using swipe keyboard? I tried doing circles on each letter and tried different swipe speeds, but I can only get "you" instead.

Comment: It's possible that "yui" doesn't exist in English phone dictionary. Or maybe you're using other language?

Comment: @Potek, "yui" is a common first name in Asia written in English. I didn't know wordflow  uses English dictionary. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: It's when you use WordFlow, it doesn't literally get the letters you swipe, but uses them to suggest words existing in dictionary. You can change keyboard language by pressing the ENG button in the bottom left corner. Also you can add keyboard languages in settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try the following:

- Type Yui in by tapping the keys individually followed by a space
- Tap on the name (it should be underlined in red)
- Tap on +Yui this will add it to the dictionary

From here, you should be able to use the word flow keyboard to correctly enter this in. This method works, because that name is not in the dictionary.

Comment: It doesn't underline in red after I type a space after "yui" or "Yui", so does that mean it's already in the dictionary?

Comment: After I swipe "yui" many times and manually choose "yui" instead of auto suggested "you", now it automatically defaults to "yui". Looks like it's learning.

Comment: Be aware that the procedure above will only work if you enable "suggest text" and then "highlight misspelled words" in Settings/Keyboard.